# How to install Poppler into virtual environment in windows (Pycharm)

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv, python-venv, poppler

I have a virtual environment I have been working on a large project in for months. I now have the need to use poppler, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to install poppler so that I can see it in my virtual environment in Windows. I have downloaded it and unpacked it into my C:programs. I have added the path to my code. I have added the path to m y PATH variable on my computer. None of it works. Any helps is appreciated. (Or an alternative to poppler).